# How to redirect if user doesn't have the correct Role? Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a SpringBoot controller and that controller returns several conffidencial information, and that information can be acces only by people with a special role, for other roles i want to redirect to other controller. 
I'm using `@preAuutorize('hasRole()')` to check the user roles. 
Please see the example

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('COLOMBIAN_PRESIDENT')")
@GetMapping("/colombia/status")
public ModelAndView showColombiaStatus(){
    //This controller can be accessed by colombian president
    //for other people, to redirect to showPublicInformation. 
}

@GetMapping(value = {"/colombia/public-information"})
public ModelAndView showPublicInformation(){
    //for any people
}
```

I want to redirect to `showPublicInformatio()` if any user doesn't have the role `COLOMBIAN_PRESIDENT`

How to redirect from `showColombiaStatus` to `showPublicInformation` if the user doesn't have the role  named `COLOMBIAN_PRESIDENT`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't go by `@ExceptionHandler` approach but by `org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandler` , that is avoid mixing generic exception handling with security exceptions.

You need to write your redirection in `handle` method in class implementing interface `AccessDeniedHandler`. In this method, you could also trace what all users tried to login to system and what users were denied access.

You can check below `auth` object for null to know if access is denied.

`Authentication auth 
          = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();`

You can create a bean of this handler and set in security config like this -
 `.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler());`

Comment: That's an approach that would work as well.  It would provide a single spot for handling Access Denied, whereas my suggestion would be more of a case-by-case basis.  I think you can mix them too!  (i.e. have a generic handler as an AccessDeniedHandler, and override as needed with @ExceptionHandler in individual controllers)

Answer (score 1):

Add an `@ExceptionHandler` to your controller, e.g.:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('COLOMBIAN_PRESIDENT')")
@GetMapping("/colombia/status")
public ModelAndView showColombiaStatus(){
    //This controller can be accessed by colombian president
    //for other people, to redirect to showPublicInformation. 
}

@GetMapping(value = {"/colombia/public-information"})
public ModelAndView showPublicInformation(){
    //for any people
}

@ExceptionHandler(AccessDeniedException.class)
public void handleError(HttpServletResponse response){
    response.sendRedirect("/colombia/public-information");
}
```

Hope this helps.